# Saving Information in Hindi

Tags: java, android

I am using this code to save the data in the file. The data that is being saved in the file is `????????`. Please help me with suitable solution.

```
File gpxfile = new File(activate, "activate.csv");
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(gpxfile),"UTF-8");
writer.write(merchantId);
```

Comment: Are you should the program you're using to read the file isn't just displaying it like "?". Try using a hex editor.

Comment: I guess your viewer is not correct. I dont think there is any problem with saving part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me.  Make sure `merchantId` contains valid `Hindi`.  For instance:

```
    String str = "मानक हिन्दी";
    writer.write(str);
```